# Calculations of nonabelian group cohomology of R^n

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, group-cohomology

I am looking at $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n,G)$ where $G$ is a finite [2-group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-group). I'm wondering if such things have been calculated. I'm afraid I can't say I know anything here, <del>past the result that this calculates group extensions of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by $G$.</del>

Any related literature would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume that you are looking at group cohomology. Then the action of $\Bbb{R}^n$ on $G$ is necessarily trivial, so $H^1(\Bbb{R}^n,G)$ is just $\mathrm{Hom}(\Bbb{R}^n,G)$ mod. conjugacy by $G$. But this is of course trivial - $\Bbb{R}^n$ has no finite quotient.

Comment: Ah, yes. And this would be true for any 2-group $G$, not just finite, as $\mathbb{R}^n$ is divisible. But, I think I asked the wrong question :-( This is still helpful, though